# issue while creating URL with objects AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am making custom URL taking values form UITextField and Passing some variables form Other ViewController.

I am using AFNetworking my code is:

```
- (void)getTheGoblin:(NSString*)userName
{
NSString *completeURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/read/",self.ipAddress];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username":userName};
[manager POST:completeURL parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    [self hideActivityIndicator];
    ChangeLightStateVC *nextScr = (ChangeLightStateVC *) [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChangeLightStateVC"];

    NSString *fullApiURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",completeURL,userName];

    [nextScr setApiURL:fullApiURL];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextScr animated:YES];



} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [self showAlert:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", error]];
    [self hideActivityIndicator];
}];

}
```

I am getting this error message:

Error:

> Domain = NSURLErrorDomain
>           Code = -1004 Could not connect to the server

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific on what troubleshooting steps that you have done already.  For example, we don't know if you have checked whether or not the server / API is actually responding to test requests from a utility such as `cURL`...

Comment: Update your library, something version AFNetworking 2.5.1....

Comment: @ryebread i have tested the GET,PUT methods they are working fine....the error comes only in POST

Answer (score 0):

Hey Sid use below code and check may be this can solve your problem

```html
- (void)getTheGoblin:(NSString*)userName
{
    NSString *completeURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/read/",self.ipAddress];
    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [parameters setValue:userName forKey:@"username"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager POST:completeURL parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
         [self hideActivityIndicator];
         ChangeLightStateVC *nextScr = (ChangeLightStateVC *) [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChangeLightStateVC"];
         NSString *fullApiURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",completeURL,userName];
        [nextScr setApiURL:fullApiURL];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextScr animated:YES];

     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         [self showAlert:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", error]];
         [self hideActivityIndicator];
     }];
}
```

Comment: what have You changed... The error comes only in POST method when i use GET and PUT they are working fine

Comment: Hey sid its seems like API problem .. please check your api in third part api testing tool.. you can use Chrome extension see this link.. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

Comment: thanx bhavin...it was the my api which is not responding...I found this using POSTMAN